# How to get /fix on NMEA data emitted on a TCP port

Tags: ros, gps-common, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a process emitting NMEA packets, similar to what gpsd does, on a TCP  port . How do I use gspd_client on this port so that I can get the fix and extended_fix rostopics? Is there any other way to get a /fix quickly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33641/how-to-get-/fix-on-nmea--data-emitted-on-a-tcp-port/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-09**:
So it's a UDP or TCP port? Or is it a serial port?

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-05-09**:
It's a TCP port

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-24**:
Were you able to find how to do it? I am also struck with the same problem?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-24**:
found it under tcp feed section in gpsd webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `gpsd_client` node uses the gps structure defined in <libgpsmm.h>, which (in the version of gpsd I'm using: gpsd3.3) uses QTcpSocket to connect to gpsd. I haven't read through the code very extensively, but it seems that if you set the ROS parameters for `host` and `port` in the gpsd_client node, it should try to connect to your TCP socket.

```
rosrun gpsd_client gpsd_client _host:=YOUR_HOST _port:=YOUR_PORT
```

Just to be clear, I have not tested this. My answer is based off of a quick read-through of the source code.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-05-10**:
Not quite! GPSD_Client needs a gpsd process running on the port. Otherwise it just quits

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-24**:
Exactly..so what  to do..?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-24**:
found in the gpsd website under tcp feed section